# Where can I find the jdb (java debugger) implementation? Who develops/maintains it?

Tags: java, jdb

I want to know how it is implemented because I want to play around with it..

Asking here because searching "jdb" on Google only shows the documentation of it. Otherwise there are tutorials and stuff, but these are not so useful when what you actually want to do is to try to hack the thing.

I also tried to navigate through the open jdk repo, but that is huge and really was not able to find something associated with "jdb".

I would really appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Oracle develops and maintains the standalone Java debugger, jdb.

As for the jdb source code:

1. Download "JDK 8 Demos and Samples" from the [Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
2. Unpack the jdk file and then unpack jdk1.8.0_101/demo/jpda/examples.jar
3. Then navigate to jdk1.8.0_101/demo/jpda/com/sun/tools/example/debug/tty/TTY.java

Or, if you download openjdk or any other jdk implementation, there should be a zip file in its base directory: java-1.8.0-openjdk/src.zip. if you unzip this file you will find TTY.java here: java-1.8.0-openjdk/com/sun/tools/example/debug/tty/TTY.java

I believe TTY.java is what you are looking for.